# Resource for learning Nach Yomi

Tags: torah-study, product-recommendation, tanach, jewish-books

I would like to start learning Nach yomi (one or two perakim a day), but I don't just want to read the Hebrew/English, since I will not end up with a proper understanding as to what is actually taking place (according to the Torah shebe'al peh). I also don't want to learn with one of the perushim, as this will take more time than I can dedicate to this. That leaves me looking for a resource that can give me the highlights without taking too much time to go through. Perhaps a perek by perek summary with essential explanations would help a lot. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can get away with no commentaries until melachim, but after that you'll need at least metzudos commentary. the melitzas are quite difficult.

Comment: I wanted the same as you and could not find a suitable resource. My solution was to learn 10 pesukim a day with the commentary of the Malbim. His commentary is very accessible so I can often read through all 10 pesukim and then learn through what the Malbim has to say.

Comment: You might also try http://www.ou.org/torah/nachyomi which includes "include audio shiurim by renowned Torah scholars" and "an accessible text synopsis of each chapter." The OU sends Nach Yomi straight to your inbox!

Comment: Judaica Press Nach. They have an English commentary on the bottom, culled from classic meforshim, that you can scan quickly, since it is in English. In fact, online, you can try learning with just Rashi in English from Chabad. http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm

Comment: a little bit relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26406/489

Comment: This won't make it go quicker, but Rabbi Hirsch has his insights into Isaiah in book 4 of his collected writings.

Comment: How is your Hebrew? Will the 929 project work? http://www.929.org.il/

Comment: [The Living Nach.](http://www.moznaim.com/the-living-nach-1421.html)

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I have found is a new book by [Adir Press](http://adirpress.com) (distributed by Feldheim) called "Journey Through Nach" (in print [here](http://www.feldheim.com/journey-through-nach-2-volume-set.html), online [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/nach-series/a-journey-through-nach/#?)). It goes through every perek in Nach and provides a short summary based on the words and meforshim. It's a great read! Highly recommended.

Other option are the summaries written on [www.shortvort.com](http://shortvort.com) which are also very good but I don't know if they cover the entire Nach

Answer (score 3):

I have recorded a brief Hebrew-English translation with all the Rashis succinctly woven into the translation. In addition, anything which is difficult to understand I add additional comments from other commentaries.

One of my goals is that unlike many nach shiurim I aim to translate accurately every word. All previous Shiurim are available in a google drive folder. I am about to start Yeshaya. Feel free to email me on rabbibrandeis@jle.org.uk

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya R Moishe, and thanks very much for the interesting answer! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us. And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Is this a free resource?

Comment: Can you link to the Google folder in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Another website to try is http://dailynach.com/ which I personally find very useful for perek summaries.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice series of summaries of each chapter of Nach by R Jack Abramowitz from the OU called Nach Yomi Companion. Available in print ([volume 1](http://a.co/dk8beYD), [volume 2](http://a.co/2xJBIeU)) or freely online [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/nach-series/nach-yomi/#?).

It is short, to the point, introduces background and context. The author is even humoristic at times.